# Error con vue al intentar compilar con gulp

Tags: vue.js, gulp

Al ejecutar mi archivo `gulpfile.js` con el siguiente comando: `gulp --gulpfile gulpfile.js` muestra este error:

```
16:37:24] Using gulpfile ~/www/webpage/gulpfile.js
[16:37:24] Starting 'all'...
[16:37:24] Starting 'task'...
[16:37:24] Starting 'js-langs'...
[16:37:24] Finished 'task' after 7.75 ms
[16:37:24] Starting 'webpack'...
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn php artisan vue-i18n:generate ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:444:11)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

Las líneas del archivo `gulpfile.js` que causan este error son estas:

```
gulp.task('js-langs', shell.task([
   "php artisan vue-i18n:generate",
]));
```

Y si ejecuto el comando `php artisan vue-i18n:generate` en el terminal, si que se ejecuta bien.

`Written to /home/lluisdev/www/webpage/resources/assets/js/lib/locales/vue-i18n-locales.generated.js`

Sabéis que causa el error? Alguna manera para arreglarlo?

He instalado vue-i18n con el siguiente comando:

`npm install vue-i18n --save` y se ha instalado correctamente, pero persiste el error.

Comment: Revisa el errorlevel del proceso cuando ejecutas el comando en la shell, recuerda que cualquier valor devuelto distinto de 0 es un error. haz la siguiente prueba `php artisan vue-i18n:generate; echo $?` si el valor es cualquier entero distinto de cero te tocará crear un wraper para artisan que siempre devuelva 0.

Comment: Hola @EduenSarceño la verdad es que no te he entendido, me lo puedes volver a explicar?

Comment: gulp ejecuta tu comando en la shell, al ejecutar tu comando, el proceso devuelve un entero, todo programa debe devolver 0 indicando que todo está bien, y otro entero indicando que hubo un error, en este caso gulp indica que al intentar ejecutar tu comando se recibe el entero  `2 = ENOENT` esto significa que a) No existe el comando que quieres ejecutar, b) El comando devuelve ENOENT. Mas creo que es el primero, es probable que gulp no encuentre `php` en el PATH

Comment: solo para confirmar la sospecha cambia el comando por este otro `php artisan vue-i18n:generate >salida.txt 2>&1 `, ejecuta desde gulp tu tarea, al terminar la tarea revisa el archivo salida.txt que se creó.

Comment: Mmm.. este comando lo utilizaba en otra maquina y me funcionaba, es cierto que algunos paquetes me han dado problema al cambiar de mac a linux, node-sass es uno de ellos, por ejemplo. Voy a probar lo que me has dicho y te comento.

Comment: Me devuelve el mismo mensaje `Error: spawn php artisan vue-i18n:generate >salida.txt 2>&1 ENOENT
`  parece que no 'entiende' el comando? Pero en cambio si lo hago desde el terminal ese comando si que funciona, sabes por donde puede ir el error?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70465/discussion-between-eduen-sarceno-and-lluis-puig-ferrer).